# Manifestation of Hecke operator on the category of abelian varieties (or motives)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, motives, hecke-operators

If we are given some postivie integer $N$ and a prime $p$, then we have the Hecke operator $T_p$ on modular forms, which is a cohomological manifestation of the Hecke correspondence
$$X_0(N)\leftarrow X_0(pN) \rightarrow X_0(N).$$
This construction happens more generally on the moduli space of abelian varieties (with rigidifying data etc). I'm wondering if the Hecke correspondence comes from some "operation" at the level of categories of abelian varieties?

If it does, and maybe even if it doesn't, one can ask if there exists a (conjectural) explenation of the Hecke operator at the level of motives?

Comment: It's not an operation, but a correspondence. But you already knew that, so it's unclear to me what the question is.